# Independence of two decks of cards, each with a different numbers of cards

Tags: independence

I am trying to get an intuitive feel for what independence 'is.' My initial guess was that variables are independent if they can't casually affect each other.

I was discussing this on a [hacker news thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11558263), and someone gave this counter-example:

> Independence is a more strict condition. The probabilities must follow
>   the rule P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) that is the rule that is used in the
>   article.
>
> Let's pick an easier example. You buy two equal decks of cards while
>   traveling abroad. When you return home, you realize that it may be a
>   deck with 48 cards (123456789JQK)or a deck with only 40 cards
>   (1234567JQK) without the "8" and "9".
>
> To make it simple, suppose that you magically know that you have a 50%
>   chance of having bought a 48 cards deck and a 50% chance of having
>   bought a 40 cards deck.
>
> One of your friend come and start to shuffle both decks, one in each
>   hand, without mixing them.
>
> If your friend picks a card from the right deck, what is the
>   probability that it's a "8"? (spoiler alert: There is a 50% that the
>   deck has only 40 cards (without the "8" and "9") and you can't pick
>   the "8", and there is a 50% that the deck has 48 cards and there is a
>   1/12 to pick the "8", so the probability is: 1/2 * 0 + 1/2 * 1/12 =
>   1/24)
>
> If your friend picks a card from the left deck, what is the
>   probability that it's a "8"? (again 1/24)
>
> Are they independent? Whatever he does with the left decks doesn't
>   affect the right deck. To get less relation, you can use two friends,
>   and put them in a different room, and make them pick the card exactly
>   simultaneously. If the events were independent, the probability that
>   both have picked an "8" would be 1/24 * 1/24 = 1/576
>
> But the correct answer is more complicated. There is a 50% that the
>   deck has only 40 cards (without the "8" and "9") and you can't pick
>   the "8", and there is a 50% that the deck has 48 cards and there is a
>   1/12 to pick the "8" in each one, so the probability is: 1/2 * 0 + 1/2
>   * 1/12 * 1/12 = 1/288. That is 2x bigger than if they were independent.

I don't have a good sense of why the example's 'correct' answer is correct, or why the two decks can't be treated independently.

Comment: I realized that 1/12 has to be incorporated twice because the example shifts to considering the probability that two people draw the same card, whereas it initially asked what the probability of drawing a certain card would be.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind "causation" generally has a strong time dimensions - the cause must come before the effect.  Probability does not have this restriction - so independence need not match with causation.  You can go the other way as well.  Take two ind rvs $A,X $ which both take values $\{-1,1\} $ with equal probability, set $Y=AX $  so that $X $ "causes" $Y $.  But we have $Pr(Y=1)=\frac {Pr (X=1)}{2}+\frac {Pr (X=-1)}{2}=\frac {1}{2}$ and $ Pr (Y=1|X=1)=\frac {1}{2} =Pr (Y=1) $.  Similarly, $Pr (Y=-1)=Pr (Y=-1|X=-1)=\frac {1}{2} $.  This means that $X $ and $Y $ are independent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate $P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8$)$. Even though the two friends are in different rooms, the events are not independent, because both the decks have the same properties. Thus, if deck 1 has 40 cards, then so does deck 2. Now consider,

$P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8 $|$ deck has 40 cards)

Now the events $A = $ "Friend I picked 8 given deck has 40 cards" and $B =$ "Friend II picked 8 given deck has 40 cards" are independent because once you know how many cards there are in the deck, the two decks are no longer "related" in any way. Thus,

> $P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8 $|$ deck has 40 cards) =
>   P(Friend I picked 8 $|$ deck has 40 cards) P(Friend II picked 8 $|$
>   deck has 40 cards) = $(0)(0)$ = 0.

Similarly,

> $P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8 $|$ deck has 48 cards) =
>   P(Friend I picked 8 $|$ deck has 48 cards) P(Friend II picked 8 $|$
>   deck has 48 cards) = $\dfrac{1}{12}\dfrac{1}{12}$

Putting this together, by the total law of probability

> $P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8) = $P($Deck has 40
>   cards)$P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8 $|$ deck has 40 cards)
>   + $P($Deck has 48 cards)$P($Friend I and Friend II both picked 8 $|$ deck has 48 cards) = $\dfrac{1}{2}.0 + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{1}{12} \dfrac{1}{12} = \dfrac{1}{288}.$

Comment: I would clarify/rephrase your initial statement that the events are not independent because the two decks are the same - they have the same properties.  Not just that there is $40$ cards in both.  So information about one deck is relevant to the other deck.